# regex match the first 3 numbers

Tags: regex

I want to match the first 3 digits that appear in a string like the following:

```
input               match
DC-9-83(MD-83)      983
B-145LR             145
DC-9-31             931
PA-28-180           281
737-600             737
```

I've used `\d{3}` which takes the first 3 digits consecutively but ignores strings like `DC-9-31`.

Comment: You can't get disjoint text portions inside a single match. You will need two steps: 1) extract with `\d(?:\D*\d){2}` and then use some kind of regex replace with `\D+` pattern, and empty string replacement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you can't get disjoint text portions inside a single match with a matching operation, you will need two steps: 1) extract the first chunk containing three digits, and 2) then remove all chars that are not digits.

The following extracts the first three digits:

```py
^\D*(\d(?:\D*\d){2})
```

Or, if you are using a method that only extracts the first match (like `re.search`, `Series.str.extract`),

```py
(\d(?:\D*\d){2})
```

Or, you may use a regex replace method (in some cases, it makes life easier):

```py
^\D*(\d(?:\D*\d){2}).*
```

and replace with the backreference to Group 1 (`$1` or `\1`, depending on the regex flavor).
Then, simply remove the non-digits with `\D+` / `[^0-9]+` pattern.

```js
var tests = ['DC-9-83(MD-83)', 'B-145LR','DC-9-31','PA-28-180','737-600'];
var regex = /\d(?:\D*\d){2}/;
for (var s of tests) {
    console.log( (s.match(regex) || [''])[0].replace(/\D+/g, ''));
}
```